# Evaluate $\iint$ of $f(x,y)=xy$ in polar coordinates, where $R$ is $(x-2)^2+y^2=4$ in quadrant 1

Tags: integration

I'm not sure if I converted correctly from cartesian to polar, but I know that I made a mistake along the way.

$f(x,y)=xy$, where $R$ is $(x-2)^2+y^2=4$ in quadrant 1
$$\int_{0}^{{\pi/2}}\int_{0}^{2}(r\cos\theta r\sin\theta)r\ dr\ d\theta$$
First integral:$$(r\cos\theta r\sin\theta)\int_{0}^{2}r^3\ dr\ d\theta=\frac {r^4}{4}\cos\theta r\sin\theta $$ 
Evaluating the first integral yields $4\cos\theta \sin\theta$.

Second integral:
$$\int_{0}^{{\pi/2}}4\cos\theta \sin\theta$$
$$u = \sin\theta$$
$$du=\cos\theta d\theta$$
$$4\int_{0}^{{\pi/2}}u\ du=2u^2$$
Evaluating the second integral yields $2$.

I tried to confirm my answer on WolframAlpha, but it doesn't understand my query. Where is my mistake?

Comment: You need to change the center of your disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** your limits are wrong. If you consider $(r,\theta)\in [0,2]\times [0,\pi/2]$ you'll get the quarter of a closed disc centred at the origin, contained in the first quadrant.

**Hint:** Change $x$ and $y$ on the circle equation and expand to obtain $r$ as a function of $\theta$. Then you proceed as you did.

Comment: But why isn't the center $(2,0)$?

Comment: When you use $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ you are assuming that the origin of the polar coordinate system is the same as the rectangular one. So, $r=0$ determines $(0,0)$ (not $(2,0)$).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
The center of disc is at $(2,\ 0),$ so you can use shifted polar coordinates
$$\begin{cases}
x=2+r\cos{\theta},\\
y=r\sin{\theta}.
\end{cases}$$